# How to use fingerprint reader( digital persona u4500) in uwp application

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

Is there anyway to use a fingerprint scanner in a uwp application project for identifying users.

Comment: I imagine there is a way. Have you done any research yourself?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/
http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/
http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I think my question wasn't that detailed enough. I am writing a biometric identification system application which uses a fingerprint reader to identify enrolled users. I have tried using the digital persona sdk but one of the required dll is not supported by uwp. I also tried using the one touch sdk but ran into the same problem. I think maybe it is because those libraries make use of windows form which is not support on uwp. I need to be able read and save user fingerprint to a database during the enrollment phase and also be able to perform one to many matching during the verification phase.

Answer (score 2):

> How to use fingerprint reader in uwp application

Please check [**Fingerprint biometrics**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/fingerprint-biometrics) official document.

> This article explains how to add fingerprint biometrics to your Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app. Including a request for fingerprint authentication when the user must consent to a particular action increases the security of your app. For example, you could require fingerprint authentication before authorizing an in-app purchase, or access to restricted resources. Fingerprint authentication is managed using the `UserConsentVerifier` class in the `Windows.Security.Credentials.UI` namespace.